# Hybrid version control & sync system?

Tags: version-control, synchronization

Is anyone aware of a hybrid version control and synchronising system?

I'm currently a happy mercurial user, but my projects usually contain a mixture of files.

Most of these (code, documentation, ...) I want to be version-controlled. This is why I use mercurial.

However, on the rare occasion I have files that I would like to synchronise between my working copies, but *not* version control.

For example, I version control the code I write to do image processing. This code can produce a whole bunch of output images which I'd like to have *synchronised* so I don't have to remember to shuffle them around my various computers, but there's no point having these version controlled.

To clarify - I am aware of extension to mercurial such as [bfiles](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BfilesExtension) and [bigfiles](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BigfilesExtension), which are handy for my image example, but I was just wondering if anyone out there knows of alternative ways to handle this. I just want the one system that I can tell "version control all files except those ones, which should be synced but have no history".

cheers!

**EDIT**: I could do something like adding a `hg marksync <filename>` that added `<filename>` to a list of files to be synced, and then adding a hook to `hg push`/`hg pull` that would (say) run `rsync` (or whichever sync tool) in the background, but I wondered if there was a less hacky solution (I think bfiles/bigfiles do something along these lines anyway).

Answer (score 1):

**Version Control** System (any) doesn't care about synchronization of

- not versioned data
- besides default pathes

If you want sync any files - use *specially designed for this task tools*: f.e. rsync

Comment: I know, I currently use rsync to shuffle files around. But I'm specifically after a single system to manage both syncing and versioning - perhaps a set of aliases I can write such that I type `svn/hg/git commit` (or whatever) and it also does the rsync automatically on the list of files I've designated as files to be synchronised.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - you can't combine a set of commands into new one in Subversion, but can define new aliases in git|mercurial

Comment: Yes, I know. I considered adding a `hg marksync` that would add the file to .hgignore and somehow add it to a list to be synced, and then adding a hook to `hg push/pull` to sync the files, or something similar. I just wondered if there's something less hacky.

Answer (score 0):

> This code can produce a whole bunch of output images which I'd like to have synchronised

Is this DATA or part of your CODE?

If data: Keep out of your versioning system, just don't go there. If it is part of your code (like layout images) check it in. Those are the only ways which are the generally accepted.

A nice solution for the data would be syncing OR generating them. So you might add a step after deployment to a server: GenerateImages().

edit: In addition to the comment made by the thread starter:

If the images are data and you need to process them on a different system don't think about the version control for your code. It is unrelated. The steps which would make sense to me, in order of processing:

Start with updating your image code, check it in versioning. Then deploy (yes this is deployment) the updated code to the cruncher computer. Now code is done.

Then you have tasks which the number cruncher should handle. Like processing the images. So start that processing from either the cruncher itself (probably some queue happens there) or from a central dispatcher.

Then you have the results locally at the cruncher. Now something has to happen with that data, so that's also part of your software. Decide whether you want the cruncher to send them to some central storage, your workstation or another location. Let the software handle that. This is the most hard part as I read through your question. Many solutions are possible from just FTP/network transfers to specific storage solutions. Willing to help but need more info about the real issues, amounts, sizes etc. on these parts.

If the new updated version of the image processor makes the old generated images obsolete implement that also in your code, by for example attaching an attribute to the files generated, a seperate folder or another indication. That way you could request the cruncher after update to re-generate any obsolete files.

Comment: I do explain in my question that these are data and that I *don't want* to put them in my versioning system. However I do want to synchronise them. Hence my original question - I want to version control some (e.g. code) and sync others (output data). Not all on or the other. This is not for a deployment situation, this is how I keep track of my code and results across the multiple computers I use at work. I use one computer *specifically* for doing all the crunching while I work at another, so I want the output data to be synced back to my other computers from the number cruncher computer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't see any relation between versioning in your data except from maybe data which may becomes obsolete when new code is deployed. I added a thorough part tot he answer, think it will help at least making the question more clear. The fact that the images are data was not clear, at least to me, from the start of the thread since image generation can also be done for non-data images which happens quite regular on deployments. Therefore please supply more info on the sync problem as also stated in the edit.

Comment: Re your edit, I understand you entirely, I agree with your analysis, and that's what I currently do. The "Decide whether you want the cruncher to send them to some central storage ... let the software handle that" -- that's what my question is about. I would love to have my code versioning program also handle synchronising of images. I don't want a separate software for this. It'd just be nice if I had a 'hg update' which ran actual 'hg update' for the versioned code, and a 'rsync ....' for all the bits in .hgignore. I just wanted to know if someone knows of that functionality already.

Comment: I think, although it sounds not very strange, it is not the way you should implement this. Versioning is a separate concern taking care of your code. Synchronization of data is another one. I would strongly recommend to handle that in some part of the application. So as a separate concert. Doesn't mean you could not also use version control for it but don't combine the two. If you eventually decide to do so you are mixing up both deployments and the actual flow. Could you tell a bit more about the images? Your code generates them. Takes some time I guess. Then where should they go?